# Lucene search of expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, search, lucene, full-text-search

In javascript i have a list

```
var list = [
{"message":"This is our first message."}, 
{"message":"This is our second message"},
{"message":"This is our third message"},
{"message":"This is our fourth message"},
];
```

I want to search in list like this

some examples -

```
first OR message
second AND message
(first AND message) OR (second AND message)
our AND (first OR message)
(first AND message) OR ((second AND message) AND (third OR message))
```

and so on.

So for every search it should return list having only elements which satisfies the search.

for ex: return list of

```
(first AND message) OR (second AND message)
```

is

```
{"message":"This is our first message."}, 
{"message":"This is our second message"}
```

I want to know if there is any existing library like lucene search etc. to achieve this purpose in javascript or any other easy method instead of writing whole code using data structure like tree in a method/function and use it.

Thanks,